# Android Studio 2.2.3 Libgdx Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, nullpointerexception, libgdx

Since I updated my Android Studio to 2.2.3 I couldn't even created new empty project without getting same Gradle build error.
I tried every solution mentioned here before.

1. I checked and re-writed my JAVA_HOME path
2. deleted .gradle file, deleted .idea file, deleted everything related to gradle
3. I Deleted everything and re-builded Android Studio from start twice
4. I re-organized build.gradle file and dependencies etc.
   At last I found a code that claimed to be working with latest version of both Android Studio and Libgdx but again I got the same error.

Here is the gradle sync message;

> Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203) at
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:3813) at
>   java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800) at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
>   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1064)
>   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1057)
>   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1023)
>   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:345)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:175)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
>   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is my build.gradle file;

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
    classpath 'de.aaschmid:gradle-cpd-plugin:1.0'
    // classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0'
    // classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'} allprojects {
buildscript {
    ext {
        gdxVersion = '1.9.4'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.2'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        roboVMVersion = '1.14.0'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

You can view the whole code from here; https://github.com/Deepscorn/libgdx-gradle-template

As I said before I can not even create a blank new project without getting same error. Could you please help me?

Note: 
  Here is my settings jar file: http://www.filedropper.com/settings_19

UPDATE!: I downloaded and installed android studio 2.0, then used Gradle version 2.10 and Android plugin version 2.0.0. For now I didnt get any errors.

Comment: I can share screenshots of Android Console settings too

Comment: clean, build, and sync

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin already tried it. Many times.